# 8051 code with variable frequency and variable duty cycle (both preferred to be user inputs at ports)

Tags: c, windows, 8051

I am building 8051 code with variable frequency and variable duty cycle (both preferred to be user inputs at ports), which will incorporate the usage of time delay in microsecond to millisecond level. I tried to create a delay function like this:

```
void delay(unsigned char h, unsigned char l)
{
    unsigned char t[50] = strcat(h,l);      
    unsigned char *stp;    
    unsigned int len,k,m,num=0,i=0;

    len=strlen(t);
    strupr(t);              //Convert all to UPPER CASE
    num=strtol(t,*stp,16);  //Decimal conversion
    for(i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        for(m=0; m<1000; m++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However I am not able to obtain any predefined function for incorporating delay in us or ms level in C, nor does the time.h header file seem to help. I am using C in Windows. Please help.

Comment: If, as I assume you are, you are looking in those header files for the delay functions you need, you wont find them. You'll need to find the appropriate header (and libs) for an 8051 microcontroller. The Arduino platform (ATMega 168, ATMega 328 or ATMega 256) has both us and ms delay functions. It's unfathomable that the 8051 doesn't have similar libraries - especially considering it's clock-speed. Try: http://www.dnatechindia.com/Tutorial/8051-Tutorial/Methods-for-generating-delay.html and http://www.8051projects.net/lofiversion/t43985/8051-time-delaytimer-routine-calculator.html

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the information. I have already done the same on 8051 assembly language. I want to replicate in C. Like for example in case of the loop above, I do not know what is the step iteration time for each iteration.

Comment: Gday. You're welcome. I've found a couple of references that talk about the topic. Basically, you cant be certain of how the compiler will output your code. The practical thing to do is to time the delay code and then make adjustments. Never worked with the 8051, so aren't familiar with its registers and instructions. If you're using a 12mhz xtal, then one would suppose that 12 NOPs in a row would give you 1us. (no idea of your choice of compiler or if it supports inline asm). Try here: http://www.8051projects.net/t18426/8051-discussion-forum/delay-loop-in-c.htm Lots of good tips there I think

Comment: Thank U Sir for the useful link.. That is helpful considering the 50 ms known delay and its repetetion logic.. !!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. I sure wish the Arduino tool-chain had a simulator that sounds as easy to use as the Keil one. Though, I can just look at the asm generated by the (x86-avr cross-compiling)gcc and count the cycles. The stopwatch and simulate functionality of the Keil suite look like they'd be lovely to have. "All I want for Christmas is....." haha.